# Can a windows client connect to a ASP.Net hosted SignalR Server?

Tags: signalr

Can a windows client connect to a ASP.Net hosted SignalR Server? Are there any additional configuration steps that would need to be implemented?

Comment: 1. Yes ; 2. Server side? No - Nothing more nothing less for this question. :L http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely - we have web and c# clients (Windows + Mono/OSX) that connect with signalR hsoted in AWS (enough buzzwords??).

You can use nuget to obtain .Net client (ASP.NET SignalR .Net client is the one for Windows)

For WebSockets you'll need Win8 on Windows clients, otherwise you'll be using LP/SSE (absoltuely fine in our experience).